# Mocking IConfiguration's GetValue<string>(string a)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm struggling to understand why the following attempt to mock reading an appsettings.config key/value doesn't work.

Class constructor:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public Client(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _config = configuration;
    var s = _config.GetValue<string>("endpoint");
}
```

Tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class ClientTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IConfiguration> _configMock;

    public ClientTests()
    {
        _configMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        _configMock.Setup(x => x[It.Is<string>(s => s == "endpoint")]).Returns("testEndpoint");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var client = new Client(_configMock.Object);

        var result = await client.GetData();

        Assert.AreEqual(null, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mock extensions methods. `.GetValue<T>` is an extension method.

You can always create a real configuration, with in process test values:

**In process**

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  ..AddInMemoryCollection(new []{
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("endpoint","testEndpoint"),
      // Other values
   })
  .Build();
```

**Environment variabels**

```
// Set an enviroment value for the current process
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("endpoint", "testEndpoint", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

// Build a config based on environment variables
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  .Build();
```

If you still want to mock. You'll need to setup: `GetSection(string key)` see the source code: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3b3645ecfd9591462132a7ba440c0a61c48ad924/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L189